# Saas Metering for web applications based on Usage

Tags: monitor, saas, usage-statistics

I have recently started knowing about SAAS .I have a web application which as to be metered based on the usage of the application.My usage criteria is the tenant actions/clicks.Can any one guide me how/what technology to use for monitoring anthink like JMX wil

Comment: you could log the clicks in the application its self, and have it send those back to you once a month

Comment: i want to know of standards that can be used something like ARM

Answer (score 1):

To metering and monitoring your SaaS apps you can do in many ways,
In my experience i suggest you better using log system integrated with your apps, you just need some logging function before or after user event. If you want to use 3rd party application to do this things for you, i suggest you use [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/) software.